# Using Map.put(String, Integer) in a loop

Tags: java, loops, hashmap, instance, put

I´ve got a short question. I am so despaired because of my problem.
I just want to put different Keys with the same Value in my Map by using a loop.
My main executes the function `einfuegen()` for multiple times. As in the following code block:

```
Woerterbuch woerterbuch2 = new Woerterbuch2();
for (Medium m : medienliste) {
    for (String s : m.getWorte()) {
        woerterbuch2.einfuegen(s);
    }
}
```

By the way I have tested all the loops and assignments of the variables.

Now `einfuegen()` should put all the the Strings `s` in the Map. See the following code block:

```
public class Woerterbuch2 implements Woerterbuch{

    HashMap<String, Integer> liste = new HashMap<>();

    public void einfuegen(String word) {
        // I have deleted all the previous unimportant code
        liste.put(word, 1);
    }
}
```

My map only contains one entry, although the function `einfuegen()` is running for more than one time and there are more than one different String that is assigned to `word`.
Normally my map should contain more than 50 different words, because `einfuegen()` is executed for more than 50 times.

My assumption is that Java overwrites the connection from `1` to `word` because 1 is always the same instance of Integer.
If I´m right I still don´t know how to fix it.

Thanks for your help.
I am really looking forward to it =)

Comment: Do you know what a local variable is?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis its an answer:)

Comment: What's the purpose of your code? Are you looking to count the number of times a word appears in a book? Assuming that's the case your `einfugen` method just adds an entry of `1` each time for `word`, whereas what you want to do is increment it (+1) if it already exists in your map, and if not add a 1 to it.

Comment: you should really create the instance of the hashmap in a constructor of the Woerterbuch2 class

Comment: Debug your code. If you want a little working piece of code see : https://gist.github.com/a791d39bf7e21dab83ab47d9bdc041df it contains your code but simplified.

Comment: After your edit, there is nothing recognizable that could exhibit the described behavior. Create a single program that reproduces the behavior without the need for code you haven’t shown us. This is called [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you have contant value for all your keys. But it matters if you are giving constant key.In case all the keys are same a single entry will be made .Debug your code to make sure that the Keys are unique.

1) Print the values in m.getWorte() to check that all keys sent are unique.

Have a look at Example Code

```
HashMap<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>();
        myMap.put("s", 1);
        myMap.put("r", 1);
        myMap.put("m", 1);
        System.out.println(myMap); // This prints {r=1, s=1, m=1}

HashMap<String, Integer> myMap1 = new HashMap<>();
    myMap1.put("s", 1);
    myMap1.put("s", 2);
    myMap1.put("s", 3);
    System.out.println(myMap1); // This prints {s=3}
```

i.e entries are made in hashmap irrespective of values being constant and entries are ignored in hashmap if keys are same irrespective of different values

Answer (score 1):

You are always creating the Map in einfuegen. This is the problem. Declare     Map liste  as an instance variable.

Example:

```
Class X{

private Map<String, Integer> liste = new HashMap<>();


Woerterbuch woerterbuch2 = new Woerterbuch2();
for (Medium m : medienliste) {
    for (String s : m.getWorte()) {
        woerterbuch2.einfuegen(s);
    }
}

public void einfuegen(String word) {
    // I have deleted all the previous unimportant code

    liste.put(word, 1);
}
}
```

Comment: In my code I declared the HashMap as an instance variable.

Comment: @patrickkr By doing this `Map<String, Integer> liste = new HashMap<>();` you are creating a new `Map` each time, that's why it always has only one entry in it.

Comment: Sorry for that mistake. Wanted to make the code shorter.
But my code still dont works

Comment: public class Woerterbuch2 implements Woerterbuch{
    
    HashMap<String, Integer> liste = new HashMap<>();

Comment: My class starts like this

Comment: @patrickkr Then remove `Map<String, Integer> liste = new HashMap<>();` from your `einfuegen` function

Comment: It isn´t there. Was my mistake while writing the post. I have edited my post.